# DRF - Django Url Filter - RelatedFieldError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Update:
This turned out to be version conflict of Django. I was using 2.0 where as DUF current version compatible till 1.11

---

I am working on DRF generic listview with DUF as filter backend.

Could you please assist me to get around this error? I am sure i am doing something wrong here with related to related fields.

When i try to filter on url I get the following error. I would like to filter on all columns of child model.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/childlist/?customer_id=2

AttributeError at /api/childlist/
'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

Below is my work so far:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Parent(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Child(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.OneToOneField(Parent, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='customer_id_fk_parent')
    used_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='rel_user')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics

from onetoone.models import Child
from .serializers import Child_Serializer
from url_filter.integrations.drf import DjangoFilterBackend


#Required columns on Child -- All columns
FILTER_REQ_COLUMNS = [field.name for field in Child._meta.get_fields()]


class ChildList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Child_Serializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = FILTER_REQ_COLUMNS
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from onetoone.models import Child


class Child_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        exclude = []
```

## urls.py

```
path('childlist/', ChildList.as_view(), name='api_child_list'),
```

Current list data as below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/childlist/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "comments": "1 is in use",
            "customer_id": 1,
            "used_by": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "comments": "2 is in use",
            "customer_id": 2,
            "used_by": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "comments": "3 in use",
            "customer_id": 3,
            "used_by": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

adding complete trace back in gist.

https://gist.github.com/just10minutes/b9add9c00ee3a14764b324ec30c65344

Comment: What happens when you set `filter_fields` like `filter_fields = ['customer_id']` ?

Comment: Can you add full traceback ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge  here is the full traceback https://gist.github.com/just10minutes/b9add9c00ee3a14764b324ec30c65344

Comment: @RossRogers I tried filter_fields = ['customer_id'], same error.  since the customer_id is OneToOnefield I guess I need to do something,which I have no clue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the same error and I think, some kind of version mismatching causing the error. Anyway I found two way to avoid the error,
**Method-1**
downgrade django version to `1.11` (`pip install django==1.11.10`)
**Method-2**
use similae django filter package, [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/#)

1. Install the package
2. add `django_filters` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. redefine your `view.py` as below

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

FILTER_REQ_COLUMNS = [field.name for field in Child._meta.get_fields()]


class ChildList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Child_Serializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = FILTER_REQ_COLUMNS
```

Hope this would solve your problem !

Comment: Thank you @Jerin, I went with django-url-filter just because of the fact it has nice url filters like customer_id__gt=1 means Greater than 1, i think such option is not avialable out of the box on django-filter.
I won't accept this as answer as of now, but I have upvoted your answer

Comment: I see a solution here https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/usage.html but it will be too much of coding for all fields. But something is better than nothing

Comment: You can use cusom filter class for that purpose, but they are not dynamic :( https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filter-class

Comment: Finally found a solution in DUF pending pull request, hope they will merge soon. https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter/pull/52

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it gave me a proper direction to look for the solution. Thank you once again.

Comment: that's looks great !